# Magento2: Getting an error: "Element 'move: This element is not expected"

Tags: magento2.4.5p1

1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'move': This element is not expected.
Line: 1427

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'move': This element is not expected.
Line: 1427

Comment: Hi @Avinash, Can you please share more information about the issue? Like where & when you are getting this issue?